# Can I disable the “You've gone full screen” notification in Chrome with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

/How/ Can I disable the “You've gone full screen” notification in Chrome with chrome extension?

I have got this manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Me",
  "description": "Disable Fullscreen notification",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You cannot. This notification is a security feature of Chrome.

Comment: Neither with extension? :/

Comment: Not even with an extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot remove the "You have gone full screen" notification, because this message is a security feature. It tells users how to exit full screen mode in case they do not know.

The only way to get in full screen without this notification is to start up Chrome with the `--kiosk` flag.

Comment: Bit annoying when your menu bar is along the top. So you cant press anything in the top middle section of the screen (due to this popup). Stranger still that [esc] doesnt work which you by default would press.

Comment: It's not a usability issue, it's a "feature".

Answer (score 2):

There's no extension for that.. but still you can start chrome in full screen mode without that message by typing in terminal

```
google-chrome --kiosk www.webpage.com
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, an extension cannot disable the notification. However, there are still a couple ways to go about disabling this "feature," such as by recompiling the source code or using the following launcher for the win32 version of chrome which automatically patches the executable on the fly, available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rn7fx94ts73jfb/chrome_v3.zip?dl=0. Source is included.

Edit: Note that chrome must not already be running for the launcher to work properly

Comment: The feature request, if anyone's interested (some guy at google apparently was, enough to take the file down from google drive): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=556906

Comment: Someone struck a nerve there, from reading your response on the tracker. I'm going to edit your snarky remark out of the answer here, as it's "noise" compared to the rest of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Because noise obviously negates the value of an answer. Pro tip: if you want users to contribute their knowledge to this site, for free no less, downvoting them for "noise" is counterproductive

Comment: 1) You can't link the downvote and the edit. The downvote is anonymous. 2) Downvotes do not need to be justified. They are expression of opinion that, in case of an answer, it is not useful.

Comment: 3) I can because, lets see, within 10 seconds of your edit I receive a downvote. Hmm

Comment: Your answer gets bumped up in the "active" queue after an edit, just saying.

Comment: Ok man, whatever you say. If the stackoverflow community feels my answers are not useful, then I won't post them here anymore. Chill. I do this for free you know..